# What does "call" mean in this java code

Tags: java, anonymous-class

I have a working understanding of Java. I understand [reserved words](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html). I also understand the basics of anonymous classes. I am reading [this](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/JavaWordCount.java) Spark example and see a "call" statement. What is the meaning of `call` and `@Override`? I see that call is not a reserved word -- but I also don't see it in the Spark docs or in the import statement. Could someone break down what is happening in this code? I get that it passes an anonymous class as a parameter (right?) -- and then that abstract class has an anonymous method called "call" (right?). But what is getting overwritten? Why the `@Override`? What does `call` refer to?

```
JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> ones = words.mapToPair(new PairFunction<String, String, Integer>() {
  @Override
  public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(String s) {
    return new Tuple2<String, Integer>(s, 1);
  }
});
```

Comment: That's a function name.  Look at the `PairFunction` interface and learn about anonymous inner classes

Comment: Also, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PairFunction` is an interface that has a single method named `call`. What's happening here is that an implementation of this interface is being created and passed as a parameter to `words.mapToPair`.

It might be a bit simpler to understand if you see an equivalent (but more verbose) way to do the same thing:

```
class PairFunctionImpl implements PairFunction<String, String, Integer> {
  @Override
  public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(String s) {
    return new Tuple2<String, Integer>(s, 1);
  }
}

JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> ones = words.mapToPair(new PairFunctionImpl());
```

The code you've shown is functionally identical to this, except implementing the interface, creating an instance, and passing this instance as a parameter to `words.mapToPair` is done in a single step via an anonymous class.

The `@Override` annotation tells the compiler to check that the `call` method signature matches the definition in the `PairFunction` interface, which has the following benefits:

- Provides a safeguard against typos
- Enhances code readability by making it clearer which methods in a class are defined in an implemented interface or extended class

In this particular case, you don't get much benefit from `@Override` because you would get a compile-time error even without it (use of `@Override` is always optional), but personally I always use it.

Answer (score 2):

What you see in this snippet is the instantiation of an anonymous class that implements [`spark.api.java.function.PairFunction`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/function/PairFunction.html). `call` is a method in that interface that should be implemented, and `@Override` signifies that this method is defined in the interface (as opposed to just adding another method to the one you're implementing).

Note: that same syntax holds for extending an abstract class, although this is not the case here.

Comment: `PairFunction` is an interface rather than an abstract class https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/function/PairFunction.html

Comment: @Dónal don't know what I was looking at, but you are right. Edited accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have a few questions

1. "I get that it passes an anonymous class as a parameter (right?)" Not quite, an anonymous class is not being passed, what is passed is an instance of the anonymous class defined above which implements the `PairFunction` interface. You later refer to this object as an abstract class, it is not abstract either. You can't construct (call `new` on) an abstract class. The class you just instantiated is concrete and not abstract. Just anonymous.
2. The meaning of `call`: This is the name of a method which any class implementing the `PairFunction` interface has to implement. What it actually does is a Spark question, but I gather from the java docs that it triggers the pairing function.
3. Meaning of `@Override`: This is an annotation which is used to indicate that the method you are now defining overrides the implementation in a parent class. In this case you aren't actually overriding any existing implementation as only an interface exists but that's the convention. The annotation has no impact on the run-time execution. I'll refer you to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94361/when-do-you-use-javas-override-annotation-and-why) for more details on when to use it.